# Drools - How to access an object in THEN clause

Tags: drools

I have a scenario when the data in the input is having different columns for one fact i.e. transposed data for e.g.

```
EmployeeID | EmpDept1 | EmpDept2 | EmpDept3 | EmpDept4 | EmpDept5
```

Now I have a lookup Department table as well e.g.

```
DeptId | DeptName
```

For me to do the lookup, one way is to create 5 rules like:

```
rule "Lookup dept-1 data"
when
    e: EmployeeData()
    d: DeptData(deptId == $e.EmpDept1)
then
    System.out.println(e.toString());
end
```

The problem here is that i have to create 5 rules (and in my case many more). Is there a way I can access the DeptData in the "THEN" clause and then write a JAVA lookup?

Or if there is any other good way, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this by using "collect"

```
rule "Lookup dept data"
when
    e: EmployeeData()
    d1: ArrayList() from collect (DeptData(deptId == $e.EmpDept1))
    d2: ArrayList() from collect (DeptData(deptId == $e.EmpDept2))
    d3: ArrayList() from collect (DeptData(deptId == $e.EmpDept3))
    d4: ArrayList() from collect (DeptData(deptId == $e.EmpDept4))
    d5: ArrayList() from collect (DeptData(deptId == $e.EmpDept5))
then
    System.out.println("Employee == " + e);
    if (d1.size() > 0) System.out.println("Department 1 == " + d1.get(0));
    if (d2.size() > 0) System.out.println("Department 1 == " + d2.get(0));
    if (d3.size() > 0) System.out.println("Department 1 == " + d3.get(0));
    if (d4.size() > 0) System.out.println("Department 1 == " + d4.get(0));
    if (d5.size() > 0) System.out.println("Department 1 == " + d5.get(0));
end
```

The "collect" function here ensures that Employee records are not duplicated and then individual applicable departments can be found.

Comment: This also ensure that lookup works even if Dept is not there in the Dept data. Rule will not return 0 if any of the Dept is NULL

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have an Employee where their Department may be listed in any of five places. The best way to figure this out would be to figure out where the department lives prior to firing the rules, and then modifying the object you pass into the rules. You're not restricted in terms of what kind of objects you pass into the rules as long as they serialize ok; if EmployeeData is currently the raw results from a database call or something, convert the parts of it you need into a new POJO and pass it into the rules.

So for your example, I would do something like:

```
class Employee {
  private Integer employeeId;
  private Integer departmentId; // assuming the only thing you need out of Department is id

  public static Employee fromEmployeeData(EmployeeData data) {
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmployeeId(data.getEmployeeId());

    if (data.getDept1() != null) {
        employee.setDepartmentId(data.getDept1());
    } else if (...) {} // other else-if omitted for brevity

    return employee;
  }

  // getters and setters here
}

public void invokeRules(EmployeeData data) {
  KieSession kieSession = ...; 

  Employee employee = Employee.fromEmployeeData(data); 

  kieSession.insert( employee ); 
  kieSession.fireAllRules();
}
```

Then you can write rules that key off of the department id:

```
rule "Employee is in department 6"
when
  Employee( departmentId == 6 )
then
  // do something
end
```

---

Alternatively, you *can* call Java methods from the when clause. Let's say we create a class called `EmployeeUtils` that has a method for resolving the department from the EmployeeData:

```
class EmployeeUtils {

  public static Integer resolveDepartment(Employee e) {
    Integer deptId = null;

    if (e.getDept1Id() != null) {
      deptId = e.getDept1Id();
    } else if (...) {} // other else-if omitted for brevity

    return deptId;
  }
}
```

You can then call this method on the left hand side like this:

```
rule "Employee in department 6"
when
  $employee: Employee()
  Integer(this == 6) from EmployeeUtils.resolveDepartment($employee)
then
  // do something
end
```

Obviously you could call it on the right hand side as well:

```
rule "Example"
when
  $employee: Employee()
then
  System.out.println("Employee is in department " + EmployeeUtils.resolveDepartment($employee));
end
```

---

**In general** it is *not recommended* to call Java methods from the left hand side because such calls cannot be optimized. When you're doing filtering like `Employee(department == 6)`, Drools can do a lot of optimization on the assertions to make your rules fire faster. But if you're calling a Java method, that's like a black box to the Drools engine; it has no idea what that Java method is going to be doing, so it must let it evaluate as-is instead of doing work to make it faster.

Furthermore, it is also generally not recommended to pass arbitrary data into a rule set. **Pass in just the data you need** for the rules to fire. When converting from another data source, eg. from a SQL query result or conversion from a spreadsheet, parse the parts of that other data that you actually need, and pass that parsed input object into the rules.

I worked for a company that would pass the database result directly into the rules. The logic was that the code was compiled, so if you needed to make changes to the rule input object you would need to recompile the code and do a new release. But database schema and rules could be external to the compiled code, so they could change without needed recompile, so just make all the data available and don't bother with a new release. This worked when the company was new and the data we were passing in was only a few joined tables; by the time I left we were passing in hundreds of tables of data adding up to several hundred kilobytes in memory, though the rules only needed a few bits of data off of maybe five tables. It was slow and wasteful. Don't go down this route.

Something like this, where you have an Employee and you have a Department data external -- joining the two is something that would optimally be accomplished in (for example) a SQL query. This sort of relational joining really doesn't usually need any decisions made on it. And if it does need decisions (eg. for example if the department code is in Dept5 then it means something different than if it is in Dept2), then multiple rules *are* in fact appropriate. But when it's just a matter of the same logic but in potentially 5 places? Don't bother doing it in rules; there's no benefit to it. Do it in Java, and then pass the result into the rules to make assertions against.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem here is employee can belong to multiple departments as well, and how many department is not fixed as well. In that case I'll have to do this in Java only.

Comment: So even though I have the whole department table in memory, I need a way to lookup through it as many number of times the employee is part of department. Now one way is to write as many number of rules, other way is to do simple loop through department object and lookup department everytime.

Comment: Is there a way I can do the second way? I mean passing the whole Dept table from the RHS so that I can loop through.

Comment: Uh, yes? Just put it into working memory? I'm still unsure why you're trying to do this in rules, though.

Comment: Also I have no idea why the fact that the employee can be part of multiple departments is a problem.

Comment: Well, its just an analogy to my actual problem. I have the department in the working memory, but then I wanted to use it in the THEN clause.

Comment: If I use it in the WHEN clause and apply no filters, then it will cause duplicates. So the goal is to use it directly in the THEN clause so that it can be looped over in JAVA to access it.

Comment: When you create 5 rules to match different departments and your employee can belong to multiple different departments you'll have multiple then executions each corresponding to the matching department. When you create single rule and 5 departments objects you'll have the same amount of executions each corresponding to matching employee - department tuple. Both cases behave the same way. Could you please describe the problem with `duplicates`? Or better create a test to reproduce it with rule, domain and test scenario code

Comment: If I create 5 rules or use "collect" or create 5 department objects, there will be same executions and there is no problem with duplicates then. My goal initially was to access Dept in the THEN clause directly without specifying in the WHEN clause so that I can write JAVA loops to do the lookup. If I specify Dept in WHEN clause without proper restrictions, that will cause the duplicates.

Comment: If it's in working memory you can access it in the right hand side. Left hand side: `$dept: DepartmentData()`, right hand side : `System.out.println($dept)`. Your structure is unclear so it is not possible to help further without accurate description of the classes involved.

Comment: No problem Roddy. But basically that is the problem to start with. If I have $dept: DepartmentData() on LHS, it will create duplicates on join with Employee. I added an answer for this, may be that may clarify more.